# enviar e-mail php

Tags: php, envio-de-email, email

Olá, meu código envia o e-mail para a minha caixa de e-mail, porém o meu "alert" nao aparece quando eu clico no enviar

Outro problema é que na minha caixa de entrada o e-mail do remetente que aparece não é o e-mail do campo que foi preenchido no formulário (aparece o e-mail que aparece é o do servidor).

Está correto o e-mail do remetente que aparece na caixa de entrada ser do servidor
?

Se não, tem como alterar para ele receber o e-mail que foi preenchido? E eu também nao consegui fazer com que o meu anexo seja enviado.

```
<?php


$arquivo = isset($_FILES["arquivo"]) ? $_FILES["arquivo"] : FALSE;
$headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$email = "meuemail@sitedeemail.com";
$mensagem = "<br>  <strong>Mensagem: </strong>".$_POST['texto'];

if(file_exists($arquivo["tmp_name"]) and !empty($arquivo))
{
$fp = fopen($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"],"rb");
$anexo = fread($fp,filesize($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"]));
$anexo .= base64_encode($anexo);
fclose($fp);

$anexo .= chunk_split($anexo);
$boundary = "XYZ-" . date("d-m-Y-i:s") . "-ZYX";
$mens = "--$boundary\n";
$mens .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bits\n";
$mens .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n\n"; //plain
$mens .= "$mensagem\n";
$mens .= "--$boundary\n";
$mens .= "Content-Type: ".$arquivo["type"]."\n";
$mens .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$arquivo["name"]."\"\n";
$mens .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
$mens .= "$anexo\n";
$mens .= "--$boundary--\r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "De \"$nome\"\r\n";
$headers .= "E-mail: \"$email_from\" \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
$headers .= "$boundary\n";

//envio o email com o anexo
mail($email,$assunto,$mens,$headers);
?> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
            alert("Email enviado com Sucesso!"); 
    </script> 
<?php
header('location: contato.php');
}
//se não tiver anexo
else
{
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "De \"$nome\"\r\n ";
$headers .= "E-mail: \"$email_from\" \r\n";
//envia o email sem anexo
mail($email,$assunto,$mensagem, $headers);
?> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
            alert("Email enviado com Sucesso!"); 
    </script> 
<?php
header('location: contato.php');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `alert` não aparece por causa do `header('Location: ...')`

Use javascript:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "De \"$nome\"\r\n ";
$headers .= "E-mail: \"$email_from\" \r\n";
//envia o email sem anexo
mail($email,$assunto,$mensagem, $headers);
?> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     alert("Email enviado com Sucesso!"); 
     window.location = "contato.php";
    </script> 
<?php
}
?>
```

O `header` trabalha com os headers da resposta HTTP, se o navegador encontrar o `Location: ...` ele irá processar o conteúdo, mas não irá exibir.

### Sobre o problema da entrega dos e-mails

Os cabeçalhos `De`, `E-mail` não existem:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "De \"$nome\"\r\n";
$headers .= "E-mail: \"$email_from\" \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
$headers .= "$boundary\n";
```

O correto seria `From:`:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "From: \"$nome\"<$email_from>\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
$headers .= "$boundary\n";
```

E aqui deveria haver duas quebras de linha:

```
$headers .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
$headers .= "$boundary\n";
```

O correto:

```
$headers .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "$boundary\n";
```

### Alternativa

Se ainda sofrer dificuldades com a função `mail`, você pode usar o [`PHPMailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), um exemplo com anexo:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = $email_from;
$mail->FromName = $nome;
$mail->addAddress($email);

$mail->addAttachment($_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"]);
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $assunto;
$mail->Body    = $mensagem;
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Erro: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Mensagem enviada';
}
```

Comment: ba isso mesmo, valeu (:

Comment: @EstácioDiFabio, ou use um `header( "refresh:5;url=contato.php" )` se quiser evitar falha em caso do js desabilitado.